# Как сделать границу под блоком из двух линий?

Tags: css, css3

Как можно вот так разделить границу внизу блока?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С помощью псевдоэлементов `:after и :before`

Answer (score 3):

Решение при помощи css `clip-path`

```css
.item {
  cursor: default;
  text-align:center;
  line-height: 30px;
  --thik: 0.2em;
  --width: var(--thik);
  --wp: calc(50% + var(--width));
  --wm: calc(50% - var(--width));
  --h: calc(100% - var(--thik));
  border-bottom: var(--thik) solid red;
  clip-path: polygon( 0%        100%, 
                      0%        0%, 
                      100%      0%, 
                      100%      100%, 
                      var(--wp) 100%, 
                      var(--wp) var(--h), 
                      var(--wm) var(--h), 
                      var(--wm) 100%);
}

.mouseover {
  --width: calc(50% - 10px);
  transition: 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mouseover:hover {
  --width: var(--thik); 
}
```

```html
<span class="item">какой-то текст</span><br>
<span class="item">какой же элемент</span><br>
<span class="item mouseover">эффект наведения</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант, можно через линейный градиент для элемента `(background: linear-gradient...)`

Результат

```css
body {
  background: #16151B;
}

a {
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #008ED6 45%, transparent 45%, transparent 55%, #008ED6 55%) bottom / 100% 3px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

При помощи [псевдоэлементов](http://htmlbook.ru/css3/after)

```css
a {
  font-size: 150%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

a::before,
a::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  /* "зазор" будет равен 20% от ширины родителя (100 - 40 * 2)
  Ещё можно прописать calc(50% - 10px), тогда зазор всегда будет равен 20px */
  height: 3px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
}

a::before {
  left: 0;
}

a::after {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Home</a>
<a href="#">About me</a>
<a href="#">Contacts</a>
```

Comment: на телефоне как то криво перенос сработал, но в целом норм ;)

Comment: Это да, но можно ограничить ссылку в одну строку)